# Outlook 2010 new assignment automatic setup

Tags: vba, filter, outlook, rules

I have just started a new job where I receive a new assignment with a job name in the subject field of an email (amongst many other emails).

I would like to build a macro that automatically takes a specified string out of the subject text - creates a new inbox folder with that name - and then sets up a rule to move a copy of all future mail with that string into the named folder.

I am doing this at least 3 or 4 times a day and would like to make this task less repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

The site is for programmers to help one another develop their programming skills.  It is not a site where you can post a vague specification and hope someone will implement it for them.  No one could implement your specification because too much is missing.  You need to start by designing the system you seek which will identify all the information you will need for a specification.

Step 1: You need something to look at every incoming email and classify it as a task-email or not-a-task-email.  Is this classification simple?  Perhaps task-emails have a subject that starts with the word “Task”.  Perhaps there is a phrase within the body of the email?  Are task-emails totally consistent?  Does a manager have a system for assigning tasks?  Perhaps they are given a list of new tasks and a list of people who could action that task.  They select a task and a person and the system creates the assignment email.  With such a system, the emails will be totally consistent.  But, if the emails are hand-crafted by the manager, they will be similar but not identical in format.  Handling inconsistencies will make this a much more difficult task.

Step 2: Having identified an email as a new-task-email, the subject must be decoded to extract the task identifier.  What is the format of that subject?  Is it something simple like “Task xxxxxxx” where “xxxxxxx” is the identifier?  Is the subject of a new assignment different from the subject of follow-up email?

Step 3: Your specification implies you can easily distinguish new and follow-up task-emails.  I deduce this from the requirement to create a new folder for new task emails and to create a rule that moves any follow-up emails to that folder.  I doubt creating a new rule for each task is a good idea.  If you have at least 3 or 4 of these emails a day.  That is 15 or 20 or more new rules per week.  Rules that will have to be checked for every new email.  I do not know how your business operates but this does not seem sensible to me.  You want to create a new folder per task which seems sensible.  Once you have finished a task, I assume you delete the task folder or, better, move it to an archive folder.  Then you will have to go into the Rule manager, find the relevant rule and delete it.  Will you do that manually or will you want another macro?

Step 4: How are you going to implement this?  I think you are correct in thinking a rule is the right approach.  Rules have lots of ways of selecting an email for processing and lots of possible actions they can perform on a selected email.  However, there is a limit to the selection and action options.  I am confident you will exceed those limits.  One of the possible actions is to “run a script”.  That is, pass the email to a macro that can do anything an Outlook VBA macro can do not just the things Microsoft thought would be useful for a rule.

Step 5: What is the scope of this macro?  You have three types of email: new-task, follow-up-task and non-a-task email.  Can you have one rule to identify new-task emails and another to identify follow-up-task emails?  If you can, you will need a macro to create the folder.  You might be able to move follow-up-task-emails with a rule or you might need another macro for that.  If you cannot identify a task-email or a follow-up-task email, you will probably have to pass every email to the macro which will handle the classification and the auctioning of the task-emails.

The above is as much of the design as I can create at this stage.  You need to finish the design and update your question.  I cannot promise that anyone will help you create your macros but at least you will know what you have to investigate to write those macros yourself.